# Want to get multiple values from an index array into a single cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way to get multiple values from an array to display in one cell

Say for example I have the two columns as below

a   1

b   2

c   1

d   3

e   2

I want all the values form the first column where the second column is 1

vlookup and index with match both only provide the first matching instance, is there a way to do this with a function or does it have to be created in a macro with VBA?

Thanks

Comment: It is a real practical situation problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the results to be shown in ONE cell you could use that VBA formula:

```
'r is the range of cells that you have a value to look for
'v is the value you are looking for
Function getValues(r As Range, v As Variant)

Dim c As Range

getValues = ""

For Each c In r
If c.Value = v Then
    If getValues = "" Then
        'Offset(0,-1) will give you value from previous coulmn
        getValues = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Else
        getValues = getValues & "," & c.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
End If
Next c

End Function
```

Use example: in cell C1 enter this `=getValues(B1:B5,1)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very useful little bit of code, though I was hoping to avoid the vba route since I want to convert this into a google sheet later and at least most of the inbuilt functions don't need to be reprogrammed!  Still, very useful for now.

Comment: And yes, I know how to use the VBA editor- I programme extensively in VBA in both Excel and Access

Comment: For a formula you could use this something like this: `=CONCATENATE(IF(B1=1,A1&",",),IF(B2=1,A2&",",),IF(B3=1,A3&",",),IF(B4=1,A4&",",),IF(B5=1,A5,""))`  Not great, but does the job....

Comment: Not really feasible unfortunately, the live data is over 1000 rows, too large for a nested if outside of code

Comment: Yeah, looks like VBA is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data is in range `A1:B5` and `Cell C1` contains the number you are looking for.

Enter the following array formula in `Cell D1` and drag/copy down till the row as required.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5, SMALL(IF($C$1=$B$1:$B$5, ROW($B$1:$B$5)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$5))+1, ""), ROW(A1))), "")
```

Being an array formula you'll have to commit above formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: That essentially does the same as Index with match, it still only returns one value, and that ony if it is the value needed.  What I am looking for is a way to do it that with this data set if the value being searched for is two, be is returned.

Comment: @MarcL - If you'll drag down the formula it will give desired result.

Comment: @MarcL - Or is it you want all the results in the same cell?

Comment: I need it all in one cell, the idea is to create a consolidated list of names based on a common secondary item.  IN this case, a list of students per teacher so the list can be used in a pivot table as a row.

Comment: Unless you have Excel 2016, there simply is no feasible way to have the results in a single cell using worksheet formulas alone.

Comment: @XOR LX I am at basic level in Formulas. I do have Excel 2016. Just a hint to have the results in a single cell using worksheet formulas alone.

Comment: TEXTJOIN would be appropriate. Can you confirm that you pass the the requirements here? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

Using helper columns this is possible with formulas alone.

[image]

Formulas:

In `D1`:

```
=""
```

In `D2` downwards:

```
=IF(B2=$B$1,D1&A2&", ",D1)
```

In `C1`:

```
=LEFT(LOOKUP(2,1/(D:D<>0),D:D),LEN(LOOKUP(2,1/(D:D<>0),D:D))-2)
```